# CA2240 warning for DataSet and DataTable within

Tags: datatable, dataset, code-analysis, compiler-warnings

I've created a DataSet that contains a simple DataTable containing five columns. When I link to the DataSet from another solution and build my project I get the compiler warning CA2240 (from code analysis), suggesting to

- add an implementation of GetObjectData to type 'SomeDataSet'
- add an implementation of GetObjectData to type 'SomeDataSet.dtSomeDataTable'

Do I need these implementations or can I ignore the warnings in my case? The serialization works as expected, so I'm not sure why I get the warnings.

I figured out how to add an implementation in the DataSet's .cs class, but how can I do that for the DataTable? All DataTable related code is auto-generated in the .designer files, so even if I changed it there it would be overwritten anyway.

Thanks in advance

G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465841/datasets-and-code-analysis), the warning about the missing implementation for the **DataTable** can be ignored. The warning is issued so that any users of the DataSet (with the DataTable in it) have to decide deliberately whether they need their own implementation of GetObjectData or not (in which case the warning can be suppressed with an appropriate comment).

HTH

G.

Comment: the link which you provided is no longer available [https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465841/datasets-and-code-analysis]

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution in Visual Studio 2015 to exclude this warnings message.

1. On Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right click the project you have this warnings CA2240 warning for DataSet and DataTable
2. Run Analyze -> Run Code Analysis and Suppress Active Issues
3. This will generate a new file GlobalSuppressions.vb or GlobalSuppressions.cs

After that, when you run Code Analyze again, the CA2240 warning is gone.

For solution, you can run Analyze -> Run Code Analysis and Suppress Active Issues -> For Solution